# Qr code is image not showing even libraries are included

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My Qr code is not working. I have already included my libraries consisting of `CIqrcode` and the `qrcode`. Is there anything that i missed? Any guides will be appreciated. Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Controller:**

```
class Testingpage extends CI_Controller{
    
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Testingpagemodels');
        $this->load->library('Ciqrcode');
        

      
    }

    function QRcode($try){
        
        
        QRcode::png(
            $try,
            $outfile = false,
            $level = QR_ECLEVEL_H,
            $size= 5,
            $margin =2,
            );
    
     
    }
    
    public function fetchqr()
    {
        
        
        $list = $this->Testingpagemodels->get_datatables_testing();
        $json = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $rows) {
         
            $no++;
            $first=$rows->ID_NUMBER;
            
            $json[]=array(
                '<tr><th><center><img src="testingpage/QRcode/'.$first.'" width="110px"><br>'.$rows->NAME.'<br>'.$rows->DEPARTMENT.'</center></th>', //I'm calling the function of my QR here.

                
            );
     

   
    }
    
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->Testingpagemodels->count_all_testing(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->Testingpagemodels->count_filtered_testing(),
        "data" => $json,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Dear friend you did not mention your environment is local or live in case of the production server that might be the extension issue.to avoid that use the below mention code to display your image.

```
                  <?php
                    // $path is path where your image is stored.
                    $path = "assets/custom/img/img.jpg";
                    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $file_data = file_get_contents($path);
                    $base64_img = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . 
                    base64_encode($file_data);
                    ?>
```

Comment: Hello, dear friend. My QRcode is not being uploaded. It is just for showing in my views. 
It works before, but after 4-5 days, it is not working. I don't know what happened... All my folders are allowed to overwrite and all permissions have been granted access.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

From my "Config" i have deleted this:

From

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html','email');
```

To

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html');
```

Now it is working. Anyone who can help me why it is an error when I include it in autoload? Is there a conflict between qrcode and email? Thank you.